# how to connect to database on another server

Tags: php, mysql, database, amazon-web-services

Could I have my php scripts on server A and connect to the MySQL database on server B?

If yes, how it would be done? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

its simple all thise above techniques are quite complicated

suppose you have database on server B and website on server A(say it has IP 192.234.12.1)

on cpanel whitelist the IP of server B

and create a new user having sufficient privileges in database (say this user is test)

then  create this user as test@192.234.12.1

Comment: Let's say server B is a database on my PC (installed via Mysql Server). Can server A (a remote shared hosted server) have access to it via a PHP script (simple PDO database connexion) ?

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

The same way you access the localhost on the same server, you change the database host to the external one. This is more a configuration issue, you need to grant your database user remote access to your MySQL, you also need to make sure your firewall allows connections on the MySQL port.

Example on Debian: http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/remotemysql.htm

Answer (score 3):

Yes it can be done.

Find out the IP address of the server A where your scripts will be uploaded. Do not forget to change the localhost to the ip address of the Server B in mysql_connect() or mysqli_connect() method.

Now go the control panel of the Server B where your Database is.

In the control panel's Homepage go the databases section and click the Remote MYSQL option.

Then add the Ip address of the Server A and click on add host.

Now you can access to the database in Server B while your scripts are running in Server A.
Mind you the fetched result will be slow cause it is getting data from database that is located on another server.

Your welcome

Comment: Hello, I have same issue. But my scenario a little bit different. In this case i want database connection for server b via server a but I want that connection object for android. Because the android project I am working it directly connect to the server and do the read write things. I know its a bad practice but still i need the solution. Android -> Server A -> Server B

Answer (score 2):

Just don't the hostname of the other box for the connection. Details depend on the extension you're using:

```
$mysql = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $schema);
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host", $user, $pass);
```

Make sure that the user is allowed to access by the MySQL server ([CREATE USER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-user.html)) and check that there's no firewall in the way.

Answer (score 0):

That is all what you [need](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_mysql_connect.asp) .

(Even you can have your scripts on server A, your web server on server B and your database on server C ...)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

You can either pass in the server hostname as an argument, or configure in php.ini.

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar challenges but here is what work for me:
 To connect to server B from server A, First, you need to allow remote MySQL access hosts in cPanel (Server B), Home -> Databases -> Remote MySQL and also whitelist the IP in the firewall (That is IP Address of B server). Then the following php db connection should work.

```
$db_connect =  mysqli_connect("serverB.com", "dbuser", "dbpassword", "dbname");
// Evaluate the connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
}else{
   //successful connection
    echo "Yes, successful";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a perfect solution for connecting another database from other servers.

```
$dbserverName = "191.238.0.2";    
$dbUsername = "lauranco_L2L";
$dbPassword = "SL92TIW5T96L";
$dbName = "lauranco_siteBits";
```

Answer (score 0):

Good old thread.

Still - of all the answers appearing here, nothing addresses about the **security**.

It is highly insecure to open up the mysql port to outside the server.

The most secure option is to keep the mysql port open to one and only localhost in all servers.

And have another php running inside the second server, make it create the desired output and deliver the same to your php (running in the first server).

Comment: I have a shared hosted server and I would like to retrieve data from a database with Mysqlserver (installed on my pc for example) with a php script from my server. Can you explain more explicitely how it could be securely done ?

Comment: Have a php script in shared hosted server, make it deliver the data columns to another php script running in your pc.

Comment: I think it is too complicated all that thing... Now I am trying to learn more about VPN trying to make a connexion between a database (Mysql Server) on my local PC to a server (shared hosted one). Do you think setting up a VPN is a good path  to security ?

Comment: Good. Instead of opening the mysql port entirely if you use VPN, fine.

Comment: Yes, I guess Mysql default port 3306 will be closed. And then I just have to set up a VPN on the remote server. Connect it from the other server (my pc). Configure Mysqlserver to accept remote connexion (bind-address+user configuration). Run a simple query to test by changing localhost to the internal ip address. Hope it will be clear as I think and that there will be no router or firewall or complicate things to configure...

Comment: You yourself had mentioned all.