# How to connect a database in my server

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to connect to database on another server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763519/how-to-connect-to-database-on-another-server)

I'm new to android programming and I wonder if it is possible to access a database hosted on my server. The database is in access or sql server.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can write a php or some other script and place it on your server and interact with the server using this file.

Comment: I can access such a database in Microsoft Access with scripts? Can you give an example? I actually ever met connectar matter to the database but it in mysql. I never met or access to sql server

Comment: I now its possible in php for sql but I'm not sure about microsoft access.