# Connect to database from another server with PHP

Tags: php, database, server

is it possible to connect to another server's database with php?
Like I have Website A thats got Database A and on this website I want to load something from a Database B of Website B. Of course I got the connection data!

Comment: Yes, it's possible..... don't use `localhost` as the connection, but the address of the remote db server, and make sure that the db server is configured to accept requests from the remote server

Comment: **[Here][1] you can find answer,please be more carefully**


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763519/how-to-connect-to-database-on-another-server

Answer (score 0):

its simple all thise above techniques are quite complicated

suppose you have database on server B and website on server A(say it has IP 192.234.12.1)

on cpanel whitelist the IP of server B

and create a new user having sufficient privileges in database (say this user is test)

then create this user as test@192.234.12.1

Gotten from [how to connect to database on another server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763519/how-to-connect-to-database-on-another-server)