# Connecting to database on another site

Tags: angularjs, ajax, database

I am an html/css developer with a more technical problem I am trying to accomplish and I am not sure where to start.

My child is in school where her grades are stored on a site called txConnect. The interface is awful so I was attempting to create a new interface where the information is pulled from their site. I have seen this done with apps in the app stores, but I am looking for just a personal web based solution and i am not sure where to start or if this is something really simple or really complicated to accomplish. Obviously I have my credentials to get the data, but making the connection is not working.

So far, i have tried curl, the method below: 
[how to connect to database on another server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763519/how-to-connect-to-database-on-another-server)
for php, i've also read that AJAX and Angular.js could be solutions, but none of these are clear answers and I feel like I am just spinning in circles and need some direction.

I have also checked github and found a few examples but most are android apps written in java that don't work and since I am looking for a webapp solution not an android app, I'm wondering if there is an easy way to do this.

Again i just really need some direction maybe a reference, or for someone to say this is incredibly complicated hire a professional...thanks!

Comment: you want to connect to this txconnect's database? What makes you think they'd allow this to happen? "Hey, can I walk into the bank vault to check somethign out? I promise to not touch anything"

Comment: If you get the information required to stablish an independent db connection, and that is a big if, come back to us at least with the DBMS. This question is too abstract.

Comment: I have seen multiple apps that do it, that's what makes me think it can be done with the username password

Comment: Did you see multiple apps that do it with txConnect? What you may looking for is access to their API.