# how connect from Heroku server to another server has Mysql DB already in node js?

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have MySQL DB has already data, and I have node js server deploy on Heroku server, I want to get the data in MySQL in server to process it, but I can't get IP for Haruko server, and I can't get another solution; can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you can maybe be more clear on this, Let me understand this correctly:

You have MYSQL Setup on Heruko with data that you have entered via the PHPMyAdmin or?
The IP for the server should be the static IP provided by you on the network inteface, If you have your pc on DHCP view the IP.

On node server you should have 'mysql'

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

module.exports = mysql.createConnection({
    multipleStatements: true,
      host: 'localhost',
      database: 'acc2000',
      user: 'root',
      password: '',
    });
```

and do the query like this:

```
connection.query("SELECT * FROM userinfo WHERE active = '0'", function(err, result){
```

Not sure if this is what you are looking for?

Comment: No MySQL step in an online server "not heroku", but my node js code in Heroku server; and I want Heroku IP because I search to a solution to connect to MYSQL online as the answer in this link "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763519/how-to-connect-to-database-on-another-server"